# Adobe flash AS 2.0

Tags: flash

I want to know for what is use "and" in AS 2.0.
If try many forma but doesn't work.

I've try something like:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    if (Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)) and (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)){
        _root.speed = 10
    }
}
```

Please show me examples

Comment: I dont know Adobe Flash syntax. but you could try this: `onClipEvent (enterFrame){ if ( (Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)) and (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) ) { _root.speed = 10}}` This simply wraps the if-statement inside parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `and` in AS 2 is equal to `&&` in AS 3.

It means both conditions must be met.

There was problems with the brackets in your code, use them this way:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    if (Key.isDown(Key.SPACE) and Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)){
        _root.speed = 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.